# How to send custom form to google sheet on multiple rows?

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to allow a user to submit a custom form that is sent to our Google Spreadhseet. The catch is I want to allow the user to submit a form that will append to multiple rows within the Google Spreadsheet.

The code I have now allows a user to send a form that will append to the google sheet once. If I try to duplicate those fields and have the user send two rows the google sheet only captures the first row and not both rows.

Google Spread Sheet

```
     |field_1|field_2|field_3|field_4|
Row 1|       |       |       |       |
Row 2|       |       |       |       |
```

HTML - FORM

```
<form id="test-form">
        <!-- ROW -->
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_1" placeholder="Field 1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_3" placeholder="Field 3" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_4" placeholder="Field 4" />
        </div>

        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_1" placeholder="Field 1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_3" placeholder="Field 3" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_4" placeholder="Field 4" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Jquery

```
     var $form = $('form#test-form'),
            url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/*******/'

        $('#submit-form').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                data: $form.serializeArray(),
                success: function (s) {
                    console.log('SUCCESS: FORM SENT', s)
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('ERROR: FORM NOT SENT', e)
                }
            });
        });
```

Code.gs

```
    function doGet(e){
    return handleResponse(e);
    }

    var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";

    var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

    function doPost(e){
    return handleResponse(e);
    }

    function handleResponse(e) {
    var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

    try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
    var row = []; 

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    } finally { //release lock
    lock.releaseLock();
    }
    }
    function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

Comment: I believe your code is not complete. How do you call the html form from your doGet() function and where do you embed the jquery code?

Comment: @ziganotschka the jquery code is added to the same index.html file that the form is on I just broke it out. Not sure on the doGet(). This code works it just doesnt work for when I have multiple rows within the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your code, but I suggest you to

### replace your jquery code through a [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) call

and modify your code as following:

Code.gs

```
 function doGet(e){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');  
    }

 var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
 var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 

 function handleResponse(row1,row2) {
     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
     var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME); 
     sheet.appendRow(row1);
     sheet.appendRow(row2);
    }
    function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <form id="test-form">
        <!-- ROW -->
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_1" placeholder="Field 1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_3" placeholder="Field 3" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_4" placeholder="Field 4" />
        </div>

        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_1" placeholder="Field 1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_3" placeholder="Field 3" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 4</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_4" placeholder="Field 4" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" id="submit-form" onclick="myJSFunction()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>

  <script> 
 function myJSFunction(){
 var row1=[];
   row1.push(document.getElementsByName("field_1")[0].value);
   row1.push(document.getElementsByName("field_2")[0].value);
   row1.push(document.getElementsByName("field_3")[0].value);
   row1.push(document.getElementsByName("field_4")[0].value);
  var row2=[];
   row2.push(document.getElementsByName("field_1")[1].value);
   row2.push(document.getElementsByName("field_2")[1].value);
   row2.push(document.getElementsByName("field_3")[1].value);
   row2.push(document.getElementsByName("field_4")[1].value);
   google.script.run.handleResponse(row1,row2);
 }
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```